# iPhone app to download/upload files

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

How can I upload/download files from/on to a jailbroken iPhone 3G?

Are there any apps that allow me to do this?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.dropbox.com/iphoneapp

2 Gb free account. No jailbreak needed.
Uploaded files can be private or be made public (accessible via http link).

Answer (score 1):

[Diskaid](http://www.digidna.net/products/diskaid) will let you manage the contents of the filesystem from your Computer.
[iPhoneBrowser](http://code.google.com/p/iphonebrowser/) will as well, but the interface is much cruder. It is free, though (DiskAid is $10).
[i-FunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) is another free option (though not open source). I have no experience with it.

On the iPhone, you can get [SafariDownloadManager](http://www.iphonedownloadblog.com/2010/08/17/safari-download-manager-updated-for-ios-4/) to download files. It's $5, unfortunately.

Once you've downloaded the files, it's likely you will need to move them to whatever application you want to consume them with, so a local filemanager is probably needed.

[iFile](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/eu.heinelt.ifile) is a really nice file manager, and is good for moving data files between apps (books, etc...). It's a few dollars, though.
I believe there are a few free filemanagers on cydia. I'm not familiar with them, though.

Answer (score 0):

Install **OpenSSH** on *Cydia* (remember to [change from the default password](http://www.cultofmac.com/how-to-change-your-iphones-default-ssh-password/20871) somehow - can also be done through ssh of course) and use your favorite SSH client. [Here](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=3221)'s a little how to suggesting WinSCP. On Mac you can use ssh with *Terminal.app* or even AFP directly with *Finder.app* with Cydia's **netatalk**.